# How can we get top trending searched listing in django rest framework using elastic search?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, search, django-rest-framework

I am using django 2.1, elastic search 6.1 and django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf 0.17.6.

view.py

```
class SchoolViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    document = SchoolDocument
    serializer_class = SchoolDocumentSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
        FacetedSearchFilterBackend
    ]

    # Define ordering fields
    ordering_fields = {
        'name': 'name',
    }

    # Specify default ordering
    ordering = ('name',)

    faceted_search_fields = {
        'top_name_hit': {
            'field': 'name',
            'facet': TermsFacet,
            'enabled': True,
            'options': {
                'size': 4,  # Override default number of suggestions
                "order": {"_count": "desc"},
                'show_term_doc_count_error': True,
            },

        },
    }
```

documents.py

```
@INDEX.doc_type
class InstituteDocument(DocType):
    id = fields.StringField(attr='id_str')
    name = fields.StringField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': KeywordField(),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
            'edge_ngram_completion': fields.StringField(
                analyzer=edge_ngram_completion
            ),
        },
        fielddata=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = School
```

I want to get result of most top most searched school.
How can i get list of top trending list ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get top size documents, you need to sort by your fields, if you want to get some school documents, you need to use school filtering.If you can't find these methods, try looking at the django es dsl drf source code .
https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl

Because I'm not allowed to write commnet, so I'm writing here.